# Redirect all web pages of old domain to new domain index

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all pages of old domain to a new domain. The new domain has a different structure so I would like every web-page under the old domain to be redirected to the new domain index page. If it is possible, only web pages should redirect, not images.

Answer (score 1):

Place this rule in root .htaccess of old domain:

```
RewriteRule !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ http://newdomain.com/? [L,R=301,NC]
```